# How do I fix bad credentials error with mule using spring security?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-security, mule

I am attempting to set basic authentication for my endpoint with active directory. I have the following configurations:

```
<spring:beans>
       <spring:bean id="ldapContextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
       
              <spring:constructor-arg value="${LDAP_URL}"/>
              <spring:property name="userDn" value="${LDAP_USER}"/>
              <spring:property name="password" value="${LDAP_PASSWORD}"/>
       
       </spring:bean>
       
       
       <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" >
              <ss:ldap-authentication-provider server-ref="ldapContextSource" user-search-filter="(sAMAccountName={0})" user-search-base="CN=Users,dc=mycompany,dc=area"/>
       </ss:authentication-manager>

</spring:beans>
```

```
<mule-ss:security-manager name="muleSecurityManager" doc:name="Spring Security Provider">
       <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="spring-security-ldap" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
       </mule-ss:security-manager>
       
       
       <mule-ss:security-manager name="muleSecurityManager" doc:name="Spring Security Provider">
       <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="spring-security-ldap" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
</mule-ss:security-manager>
       
<flow name="http-basic-authenticationFlow">
       <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
           path="/validate" doc:name="HTTP" allowedMethods="GET"/>
       
       
       <http:basic-security-filter
           realm="mule-realm"
           securityProviders="spring-security-ldap"
           />
       <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
       
       <set-payload
           value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;response validated&quot; }"
           mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Set Payload" />
</flow>
```

when sending a GET request through postman with the correct credentials, I get the following error:

```
Message               : Authentication Attempt Failed.
Payload               : {NullPayload}
Payload Type          : org.mule.transport.NullPayload
Element               : /http-basic-authenticationFlow/processors/1 @ my-apis:null:null
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
```

Comment: Just following your question info. Because of `BadCredentialsException`, are you sure credentials are correct? Are you sure backend validates credentials correctly?

Comment: I have tested my connection with ldap connector and it is working fine.